# tikz: anchor to rectangle split on a fraction of a side

Tags: tikz-pgf, anchor

Is it possible to anchor to a rectangle with a specification not based on angles?

For instance, in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\definecolor{cerulean}{cmyk}{0.94,0.11,0,0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every text node part/.style={align=center},  
  every two node part/.style={align=left},  
  font={\sf}, rectangle split part fill={cerulean!10, white}]
  \node (A) [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rounded corners, ultra thick, draw, text width=5cm,  minimum height=1cm]
  {\nodepart{text} {\bfseries A}
    \nodepart{two}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      $\;$B
    \end{tabular}};
  \node (B) [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rounded corners, ultra thick,draw, text width=5cm,  minimum height=1cm , below=2cm of A]
  {\nodepart{text} {\bfseries B}
    \nodepart{two}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      $\;$C
    \end{tabular}};
  \draw[<->,draw, thick,>=angle 45] (A.south) -- node[right=0.1cm, font={\sf\bfseries}] {R} (B.north);
  \draw[<->,draw, thick,>=angle 45] (A.-30) -- node[right=0.1cm, font={\sf\bfseries}] {P} (B.30);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

The rightmost line has anchors `{A.-30}` and `{B.30}`.
I would like to know if there is a way to anchor a line to points at 1/4 of a side of a rectangle, in a way similar to `south` or `north`, withouth specifing the angle (since if the rectangle change its height, then I must
change the angle, like in the following picture, where I just added a new element to the `B` rectangle).

[image]

I am looking for a simple solution, like a simple fraction of one side (either horizontal or vertical) that allows me to change the boxes without changing the specifications of the anchors.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The calc tikzlibrary allows things like `($(node.south west)!0.667!(node.south east)$)` for some node named `node`..

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo!

Comment: You can also use perpendiculars intersection: `\draw[<->,draw, thick,>=angle 45] (A.-30) -- node[right=0.1cm, font={\sf\bfseries}] {P} (B.north-|A.-30);`

Comment: @JohnKormylo, when I say `($(node.south west)!0.667!(node.south east)$)` it works. When I try to do the same for the east side, `$(node.east north)!0.667!(node.east south)$` there is an error message: `ERROR: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `east' (in 'east north').`

Comment: north east and south east.  By convention, north and south always come first.